# android easy mini function server?

Tags: android

In my app, I only need to update one link every day, so I am looking for a tool that I can update link daily on the remote and my app can just use the tool link.

Is there any tool achieving this function? I searched all the internet and cannot find a such simple tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) it is free and easy to use, you would have to manually update the links but.

For a more automated solution create a MySQL or NoSQL db and add the data for each day, create an api which gets the data from the db and returns it. Your app will communicate with api to get the data.